# How to set specific sheet indices to a cell with Google Apps Scirpt

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have sheet about 410. What I want is change values in some sheet which sheetnumber [4] to [ 370].
But, Down code is changing all of sheet cells value.

```
function UpdateCell()
{
  const NotationRange = "J1"; 
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  const year = 2020; 
  sheets.forEach
  (
    (sheet) => { const sheetName = sheet.getName();
                 sheet.getRange(NotationRange).setValue(year+'.'+sheetName);
               }
  )
}
```

How can I put specific sheet location number in the code...

Comment: What is `sheetnumber [4] to [ 370]`? Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: I used to another code but I don't know aplly { var sheet = source.getSheets()[0]; } -->  [0] is sheet number .. and [0] means first sheet of spreadsheet,, so what I mean that sheetnmber [4] to [370] is intervening sheets from fifth sheet to three hundred seventy one sheets

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to use the sheets of the sheet indexes from `4` to `370`.

  - You don't want to use all sheets.
- In this case, `4` and `370` are `sheets[4]` and `sheets[370]` of `const sheets = ss.getSheets()`, respectively.

For this, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- When `sheets.forEach()` is used, all values in `sheets` are used. So here, I would like to propose to use the for loop.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

From:

```
sheets.forEach
(
  (sheet) => { const sheetName = sheet.getName();
               sheet.getRange(NotationRange).setValue(year+'.'+sheetName);
             }
)
```

To:

```
for (let i = 4; i <= 370; i++) {
  const sheet = sheets[i];
  const sheetName = sheet.getName();
  sheet.getRange(NotationRange).setValue(year+'.'+sheetName);
}
```

- By this modification, the sheet indexes from `4` to `370` are used in the loop.

Comment: thank you from korea . It's awesome and usefull. Now I can go home early. have a good day!!

Comment: @riore El Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.